# AttributeError: module 'multiprocessing' has no attribute 'Value'

Tags: python

No se mucho sobre Python, actualmente me estoy instruyendo en el tema y en una de mis prácticas:

```
def retirar(saldo, lock):
    for _ in range(2000):
        lock.acquire()
        saldo.value = saldo.value - 1
        lock.release()

def deposito(saldo, lock):
    for _ in range(4000):
        lock.acquire()
        saldo.value = saldo.value + 1
        lock.release()

def transacciones():
    saldo = multiprocessing.Value('i', 10000) 
    lock = multiprocessing.Lock()

    proceso1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=retirar, args=(saldo, lock))
    proceso2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=deposito, args=(saldo, lock))

    proceso1.start()
    proceso2.start()

    proceso1.join()
    proceso2.join()

    print("Saldo final: {}".format(saldo.value))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for _ in range(100):
        transacciones()
```

Me arroja el siguiente error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Prácticas Python\multiprocessing\multiprocessing.py", line 32, in <module>
    transacciones()
  File "d:\Prácticas Python\multiprocessing\multiprocessing.py", line 16, in transacciones
    saldo = multiprocessing.Value('i', 10000) 
AttributeError: module 'multiprocessing' has no attribute 'Value'
```

Sería de gran ayuda el que me ayudaran a entender y solucionar el error, de antemano muchas gracias por la atención brindada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error fue que mi script se llamaba multiprocessing.py, lo renombré y funcionó con normalidad.